# Is there a way to eliminate multiple computations of same lambda expression occurring multiple times in a Python expression?

Tags: python, lambda

I was attempting to exemplify python lambda expressions with the well-known formula for triangle's area. Given the three sides **a**, **b**, and **c** and the semi perimeter **s** as **(a+b+c)/2**, the area is square root of **(s * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c))**. So, I wrote the python code:

```
s = lambda a, b, c : (a + b + c)/2 #Line 1
area_tri = lambda a, b, c : (s(a,b,c) * (s(a,b,c)-a) * (s(a,b,c)-b) * \
   (s(a,b,c)*c)) ** 0.5
area_tri(1, 2, 3)
```

The statement computing **area_tri** has to compute **s(a, b, c)** four times. So, I thought if I could write something like:

```
semi = s
```

after Line 1 and replace every occurrence of **s(a,b,c)** with **semi** in the **area_tri** computation statement. But, it would produce an error that **a, b** and **c** are unknown symbols. Is there an error-free alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After python3.8, you can use **walrus operator**`:=`:

```
area_tri = lambda a, b, c: ((semi := s(a, b, c)) * (semi - a) * (semi - b) * (semi - c)) ** 0.5
```

For earlier versions, the best way is to define a function:

```
def area_tri(a, b, c):
    semi = s(a, b, c)
    return (semi * (semi - a) * (semi - b) * (semi - c)) ** 0.5
```